# ActiveMQ - JDBC persistence MySQL: ACTIVEMQ_MSGS is empty

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, activemq-classic

I'm implement the persistence with MySQL (http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support.html).
But when I check this table, it's always empty.

[Image of MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vogh.png)

[activemq.log]

```
2015-12-17 15:16:57,966 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, ID:PTLSF07-63181-1450361138461-0:1) is shutting down | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,969 | INFO  | Connector openwire stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,971 | INFO  | Connector amqp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,972 | INFO  | Connector stomp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,974 | INFO  | Connector mqtt stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,974 | INFO  | socketQueue interrupted - stopping | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer | ActiveMQ Transport Server Thread Handler: mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
2015-12-17 15:16:57,977 | ERROR | Could not accept connection : java.lang.InterruptedException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Transport Server Thread Handler: mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
2015-12-17 15:16:57,989 | INFO  | Connector ws stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:57,994 | INFO  | PListStore:[C:\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] stopped | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:58,198 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, ID:PTLSF07-63181-1450361138461-0:1) uptime 11 minutes | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:58,199 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (localhost, ID:PTLSF07-63181-1450361138461-0:1) is shutdown | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:58,200 | INFO  | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@200669bf: startup date [Thu Dec 17 15:05:33 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:16:58,211 | INFO  | Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook
2015-12-17 15:17:00,588 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@200669bf: startup date [Thu Dec 17 15:17:00 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 15:17:01,779 | INFO  | PListStore:[C:\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 15:17:01,810 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: JDBCPersistenceAdapter(org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@2311fe17) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-17 15:17:02,196 | INFO  | Database adapter driver override recognized for : [mysql_connector_java] - adapter: class org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.MySqlJDBCAdapter | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
```

[activemq.xml]

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker.
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#mysql-ds"/> 
        </persistenceAdapter>

<!-- 
        <persistenceFactory>
            <journalPersistenceAdapterFactory 
                journalLogFiles="5" 
                dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data"
                dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
        </persistenceFactory>
-->

          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="5 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!-- MySql DataSource Setup -->
    <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
         <property name="username" value="user"/>
         <property name="password" value="pass"/>
         <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Could you please help me fixing this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For the persistent adapter to work remove , the `dataDirectory` from the `<broker>` & `<jdbcPersistenceAdapter>` tags. This way the kahaDb won't be initialised.